# How to use ES6 module in ember.js (with ember cli)?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, es6-modules

Standard project set up with ember cli seems to be using ES6 modules when I generate controllers/routes/models etc. with the cli. Sometimes though I want to import/export an additional function/module ie. I may want to write a function that I use in the controller in a separate file.
When I try to import the function in the standard ES6 way ember-cli seems to have a problem with handling it.
Let's say I've created controller with:

```
ember g route tesit
```

then I create a function in app/routes/testit/logger.js

```js
const logger = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};

export default logger;
```

and import it in my controller app/routes/testit.js:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';
import logger from './testit/logger.js'

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel() {
    logger('it works');
  }
});
```

then I get the following error:

`Error: Could not find module myproject/routes/testit/logger.js imported from myproject/routes/testit`

How can I resolve it?

Comment: remove `.js` from `import logger from './testit/logger.js'`

Comment: thanks ykaragol, interesting - babel would work with the extension as well as without it. That works though - awesome! :-)

Comment: thanks Alan Bogu. I copied it as answer and added a reference.

Comment: Also note that this is what Ember would consider a util and might be better put in the utils folder. At some point once the new Ember resolver is in place that may be a requirement...

Answer (score 4):

Remove `.js` extension from `import logger from './testit/logger.js';` line.

See [`Description` section](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Description) from MDN.